# All post-requests to Restful webservice gives Http 415

Tags: apache, tomcat, jackson, jersey-2.0

Look at the Response and Request headers

[image: Look at the Response and Request headers]

I have a Restful webservice (Jersey version 2), running on Tomcat 9 using Apache as a proxy. I use JSON as a protocol (Jackson) for exchanging data between the client and the server. The GET-requests works fine. They return data at json-format.

But the POST-requests has stopped to function. They receive data at json format. The request fails before the server method is reached.
My Webservice worked fine earlier. I think the change came with putting Tomcat behind Apache. But I'm not sure. I use `mod_proxy`
The first picture shows the client and the network response. I can see that the Response do not contain JSON as content-type, but the Request is asking for it (as I understand it).

If I understand this right, how do I get the Response to accept JSON ?
Help is really appreciated, as I have struggled with this for a long time. Nothing I find on internet gives the correct answer.

I guess it is something wrong in configuration files.

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>PlanYourProject</display-name>

    <!-- Define ServletContainer of Jersey -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PlanYourProject</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Define the ResourceConfig class -->
        <init-param>
            <!-- <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>App.App</param-value> -->
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                 <param-value>Project</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all the URLs to the Jersey ServletContainer -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PlanYourProject</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jwt.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>PlanYourProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PlanYourProject Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
        <dependency> <!-- FOR SERVLET 3.x -->
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/rest-api-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wisdom-framework/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wisdom-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34_1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/smtp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <!-- Dette er Java versjon -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>PlanYourProject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

server.xml (part of):

 <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

Here is some sample-code, but the problem is for all Post-requests in my webservice.
**This is from the client:**

```
createPayment(obj){
        var url = window.location.origin + "/PlanYourProject/rest/CustomerAdministration/create_payment";
        var ajaxRequest = new UI_AjaxRequest(); 
        var id = obj.button_id;
        var ids = id.split('_');
        var value = obj.button_value;
        var values = value.split(' ');
        var price = new Object();
        price.dbname = sessionStorage.database_name;
        price.type = ids[3];
        price.period = ids[4];
        price.price = values[1];
        price.currency = values[2];
        price.language = sessionStorage.responsible_language;
        id = id.replace("input","info");
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        price.typetext = element.value;
        ajaxRequest.startPostRequest(url, price, obj.paymentCreated, obj.paymentFailed);
}
startPostRequest(argUrl, dataObj, argSuccessFunction, argFailureFunction) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
            var req = new Ajax.Request(argUrl,{
                method :      'POST',
                parameters :  JSON.stringify(dataObj),
                contentType : 'application/json',
                dataType :    'json',
                onSuccess :   argSuccessFunction,
                onFailure :   argFailureFunction
            });
```

**This is from the server:**

```java
@POST
@Path("/create_payment")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createPayment(Price price,@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException  {
    String redirectUrlJson;
    String redirectUrl;
    try {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        redirectUrl = customerDao.CreatePayment(price, request);
        redirectUrlJson = om.writeValueAsString(redirectUrl);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        redirectUrlJson = "{\"result\" : \"" + ex.getMessage() + "\" }";    
    }
    return redirectUrlJson;
}
```

**/etc/apache2/apache.conf:**

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

#
# Setter Response og Request headers til å godta JSON. 
# Brukes av mod_headers. 
#
# Enables :  
#           a2enmod headers
#           apache2 -k graceful
#
Header set Content-Type "application/json; charset=UTF-8"  
# RequestHeader set Content-Type "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf:**

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

    # If you want to use apache2 as a forward proxy, uncomment the
    # 'ProxyRequests On' line and the <Proxy *> block below.
    # WARNING: Be careful to restrict access inside the <Proxy *> block.
    # Open proxy servers are dangerous both to your network and to the
    # Internet at large.
    #
    # If you only want to use apache2 as a reverse proxy/gateway in
    # front of some web application server, you DON'T need
    # 'ProxyRequests On'.

    #ProxyRequests On
    #<Proxy *>
    #   AddDefaultCharset off
    #   Require all denied
    #   #Require local
    #</Proxy>

    # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
    # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
    # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
    #ProxyVia Off

</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**log file from apache:**

```
[Wed Oct 10 00:09:57.556556 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 833:tid 140467586079680] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 10 00:09:57.556678 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 833:tid 140467586079680] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 10 00:09:57.556685 2018] [core:notice] [pid 833:tid 140467586079680] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 10 22:02:07.007600 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 782:tid 139711419993024] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 10 22:02:07.042839 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 898:tid 139711419993024] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 10 22:02:07.044021 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 898:tid 139711419993024] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 10 22:02:07.044050 2018] [core:notice] [pid 898:tid 139711419993024] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Oct 11 00:10:26.012155 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 898:tid 139711419993024] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: Instead of referencing external pictures could you please add the code here. Also please add the apache http configuration that forwards to the tomcat. - Do you use mod_proxy for this?

Comment: I do not know where I find the apache http configuration that forwards to Tomcat. It is mod_proxy I use.  The only connection I know between Apache and Tomcat is in server.xml. My son helped me with setting ut Apache, so I'm really lost :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a JSON provider. You have some Jackson dependencies, but they are not the JAX-RS provider. What you need is the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

That should do the trick. This will allow the incoming JSON to be converted to the `Price` in your resource method parameter.